# onClick Function "this" Returns Window Object

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, window, this

I've come across a head scratching issue with my JavaScript application.

If I write an element like this:

```
<li onClick="alert(this.tagName)"></li>
```

I get "LI."

However if I do this:

```
<li onClick="foo()"></li>
```

Where "foo()" is:

```
function foo(){ alert(this.tagName); }
```

I get "undefined."

I am away how "this" is supposed to work in regards to attached functions. But, I am baffled because "this" is not picking up the element, but apparently defaulting to "window." I can't figure out why this is happening.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Try searching first, please. There are many duplicates. `this` is "dynamically bound" to the *receiver* of the function, or to the global object (e.g. `window`).

Comment: Hint: `<li onClick="foo()"></li>` wraps `foo()` inside of an anonymous function, rather than calling `foo()` directly.

Comment: Hint2: The meaning of *this*, is relative to where you use it.

Comment: You may find it to be more sensible if you remove the inline event handlers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's because you aren't passing a reference to *this* in the JavaScript function call. *this* in the JavaScript function doesn't refer to the same object as in the *onClick* example. Try this instead:

```
 <li onClick="foo(this)"></li>

 function foo(item){ alert(item.tagName); }
```

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: `this` is set entirely by how a function is called (ignoring [ES5 bind](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5)). The calling context (i.e. global or function context, which establishes scope) is irrelevant. If `this` is not set by the call, it will default to the global object in non-strict mode regardless of where a function was called, and `this` can be set to any object when called from any context (i.e. it has nothing to do with scope).

Comment: To add portability you could also use like so: <li onClick="foo.call(this)"></li> Called function will inherit the calling element as "this".

Answer (score 4):

In an inline listener:

```
> <li onClick="alert(this.tagName)"></li>
```

The onclick attribute value is effectively wrapped in a function and called with the element set to this, e.g.

```
function anon() {
  /* attribute value */
}

anon.call(element);
```

When you put a function in the body, you are essentially getting:

```
function anon() {
  foo();
}
```

Here, `this` within `anon` will be the element, but since `foo` is called without setting `this`, it will be undefined. In non-strict mode, `this` will default to the global object (`window` in a browser). In strict mode, `this` inside `foo` will be undefined.

One solution is to pass an element reference to the function:

```
<li onclick="foo(this)" ... >
```

then in the function:

```
function foo(callingElement) {
  ...
}
```

or even:

```
<li onclick="foo.call(this)" ... >

function foo() {
  var callingElement = this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers already mention, the value of `this` will depend on how the function that contains it is called. But since your example is about event handlers, I'd like to highlight what cjc343 said on the comments:

> You may find it to be more sensible if you remove the inline event handlers.

That's pretty simple, actually. Considering this HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="item1">item 1</li>
    <li id="item2">item 2</li>
    <li id="item3">item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The following JavaScript will account for both removing inline handlers, and using delegation:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
list.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    console.log("this is the element the event is bound to: " + this.id);
    console.log("the event target is the clicked element: " + evt.target.id);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J3Gje/

That will work on all browsers compliant to the W3C event model, including IE9. For older IE, you have to use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`, and prepend the event names with `"on"`. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener#Compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

Another option, so you don't have to pass **this** as a param, is to use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). It's a built in mechanism to set the value of **this** within a function. Though I would point out, adding your event handlers directly to your html is a bit antiquated. You may want to check out a JS framework for event delegation ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/), [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/), [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/), etc.).

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bboone/Q2CkV/2/

**HTML**

```
<div onClick='alert(this.tagName);'>test</div>
<div onClick='foo.call(this);'>test2</div>​
```

**JS**

```
function foo(){ alert(this.tagName); }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are new to JavaScript do not use the `this` or `new` keyword, because either you will get it wrong or your code will be unnecessarily inefficient and more complex.  What you are trying to accomplish, though is the following:

```
<li onclick="foo(this)">some text</li>
```

In that example the click event of that list item fires a function named foo.  The `this` keyword is passed in as a variable.  The `this` keyword merely refers to the entity that called the function in question and if it cannot find that entity it will refer to the `window` object of the browser.  In this case the entity that called the function is the list item node from the DOM.

I still suggest never using `this` keyword in order to avoid this kind of confusion moving forward.

EDIT:  Also, do not use a tagName property as this is not standard.  Instead use the `nodeName` property.

Comment: `Element.tagName` is provided by DOM level 2, just like `Node.nodeName`.  Your recommendations to avoid `this` and `new` are troubling - if you learn to use them, they are not confusing.

Comment: @Dennis I disagree. I have never seen any use of `this` that is more clear or simple than similar logic not using that keyword. Consequently, I have seen numerous examples of people coming from other languages attempting to create class structures with `this` in order to bend JavaScript to their prior experience, which is not rational. `this` is also the pronoun of JavaScript, and pronouns do not serve the interests of programming. I am more than happy to accept down votes as I will continue to stand by my opinion.